# Install RC1 version with composer for Drupal 8 module

Tags: module, composer-php, installation, version, drupal-8

I need to install a **specific RC1 version** for a Drupal 8 module **with composer**.

Example: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group (8.x-3.0-rc1)

I've tried to use the constraint: '8.x-3.0-rc1'.

```
composer require drupal/field_group:8.x-3.0-rc1
```

The error message:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint 8.x-composer: Invalid version string "8.x-composer"
```

Comment: Did you tried `composer require drupal/field_group:3.0-rc1`?

Comment: Yes, that is working fine. I was confused about the "8.x-". I can leave that behind and just use the part after this.

Comment: That *is* confusing. Drupal uses composer in a crazy way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the version of the module / theme you want to download as follows:

composer require `drupal/<modulename>:<version>`

For example:

```
composer require 'drupal/token:^1.5'
composer require 'drupal/simple_fb_connect:~3.0'
composer require 'drupal/ctools:3.0.0-alpha26'
composer require 'drupal/field_group:3.0-rc1'
composer require 'drupal/token:1.x-dev'
```

To avoid problems on different terminals/shells, surround the version in quotes as in the examples above. In these examples, the versions map as follows:

- `^1.5`: maps to the latest stable `8.x-1.x` release of the module.
- `~3.0`: maps to the latest stable `8.x-3.x` release of the module.
- `3.0.0-alpha26`: maps to version `8.x-3.0-alpha26`
- `3.0-rc1`: maps to version `8.x-3.0-rc1`
- `1.x-dev`: maps to `8.x-1.x-dev`

For more on version constraints with ~ (tilde) and ^ (caret) see [Next Significant Release Operators](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators).